# Merge two properties file using shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell, unix

How to merge two properties file, using shell scripts for example : - if i have two properties file like

```
first.properties
/test/file="anish"
/test/version=3.0

second.properties
/test/author=nath
/test/version=2.0
```

if i merge first.properties over second.properties then common existing property should taken from the first.properties so my output should look like

```
final.properties
/test/file="anish"
/test/version=3.0
/test/author=nath
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Another way:

```
$ awk -F= '!a[$1]++' first.properties second.properties
```

The input to this awk is the content of first file followed by second file. `!a[$1]++` prints only the first occurence of a particular key, hence removing duplicates apparing in the 2nd file.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat first.properties second.properties | awk -F= '!($1 in settings) {settings[$1] = $2; print}'
/test/file="anish"
/test/version=3.0
/test/author=nath
```