# docker run passing command line params as config file

Tags: docker

In `docker-compose` there is a `.env` file which can hold all the properties of used in `docker-compose.yml`

Is there an equivalent of that in `docker run` command? I have exhausted the docs and forums but couldn't find any answers.

Here is what I am looking for:
Rather than 
`docker run -v /dir1:/dir1 -v /dir2:dir2 -p 80:80 repo/image`

run `docker run -config config.yml repo/image'` with `config.yml` file holding all the property mappings

Comment: Docker has no support for this. That is what Compose is for, simplifying this process of running containers with many parameters. However, you can write a simple script that does what you want.

Comment: Just re-iterating that compose is exactly this.

Answer (score 3):

One option could be to have the parameters stored in a file and just get the string of the file using cat:

```
docker run $(cat config.file) repo/image
```

Where config.file content should be something like:

```
-v /dir1:/dir1 -v /dir2:dir2 -p 80:80
```

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to be an unfortunate gap. The best workaround I've found is to use `docker-compose` with a docker-compose.yml file to define the container and all it's flags and then use

```
docker-compose run your-service-name-here
```

To just run a single one-off container.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunatelly, it is no way to do this as you describe.
However you can add several `env config files` and merge them to one `.env` like describe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017577/merge-two-properties-file-using-shell-scripts)

```
$ awk -F= '!a[$1]++' first.env second.env > .env
```

Comment: I think the original question was asking for properties that aren't env variables, like setting up volume bindings?