# Shell script for merging dotenv files with duplicate keys

Tags: shell, environment-variables

Given two dotenv files,

```
# file1
FOO="X"
BAR="B"
```

and

```
# file2
FOO="A"
BAZ="C"
```

I want to run

```
$ ./merge.sh file1.env file2.env > file3.env
```

to get the following output:

```
# file3
FOO="A"
BAR="B"
BAZ="C"
```

So far, I used the [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) module to parse the files into dictionaries, merge them and write them back. However, I feel like there should be a simple solution in shell that rids myself of a third-party module for such a basic task.

---

### Answer

Alright, so I ended up using

```
$ sort -u -t '=' -k 1,1 file1 file2 | grep -v '^$\|^\s*\#' > file3
```

which omits blank lines and comments. Nevertheless, the proposed `awk` solution works just as fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two properties file using shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017577/merge-two-properties-file-using-shell-scripts)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Another quite simple approach is to use sort:

```
sort -u -t '=' -k 1,1 file1 file2 > file3
```

results in a file where the keys from file1 take precedence over the keys from file2.

Answer (score 4):

Using a simple awk script:

```
awk -F= '{a[$1]=$2}END{for(i in a) print i "=" a[i]}' file1 file2
```

This stores all key values in the array `a` and prints the array content when both files are parsed.

The keys that are in `file2` override the ones in `file1`.

Answer (score 0):

To add new values only from file2 and NOT overwrite initial values from file1. Omit spaces from file 2.

```
  grep "\S" file2  >> file1
  awk -F "=" '!a[$1]++' file1 > file3
```